# CSS Psuedo elements rendering issue on Sony Xperia Tablet Z

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am developing a site for a client and having an issue where the pseudo elements (::before & ::after) are rendering funny white lines. It is only on this tablet that I have this issue and as Murphy's law would have it that's what my client is testing on.

Here is an example of how it's being rendered:

[image]

HTML:

```
<li>
  <div class="arrow_box" id="step2">STEP 2</div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="arrow_box" id="step3">STEP 3</div>
</li>
```

And here is the CSS that I am using:

```
.active .arrow_box {
    background-color: #ff3838;
}

.active .arrow_box:after {
    border-left-color: #ff3838;
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.active .arrow_box:after {
    border-left-color: #ff3838;
}

.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-left-color: #fff;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Comment: Is your content being scaled in any way? I've had occasions where even desktop browsers will render gaps if the viewport is scaled to a non-integer scaling. Also -- more CSS would help here -- or even better, a fiddle that has all the CSS necessary to render your elements -- otherwise I can't test anything.

Comment: I found that some browsers can't handle this kind of breadcrumb menu technique. I fear there will be only a random work-around for this bug. Did you try to give the whole `<ul>` a black background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Issue came in with decimal pixel values in the width of the element. This was hard to steer clear of with percentages, so I converted to whole pixel values, which sorted out the issue.

Thanks for the help from everyone that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and had to keep each `<li>` a percentage width. Looked great on desktops, but those same lines appeared on tablets.
I know this is an old post, but here's my workaround in case anyone needs this in the future.
Using the code you provided, the changes would be:

```
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {left: 99%;}
li {margin: 0 1px;}
```